# Clickable Flat list item with Navigate something page in React Native

Tags: react-native, button, navigation, react-native-flatlist, touchableopacity

I put the local image and button in the flat list.

1. How do I retrieve an image from Json?
2. How do I move to another page when I click?

I'd like to divide up the script.

This is my code

```
export default class HotFlatList extends Component {
    render() {
    return(
        <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'column'}}>
            <View>
                <FlatList style={{backgroundColor:'block', opacity: 1}}
                    horizontal={true}
                    data={hotFlatListData}
                    renderItem={({item, index}) => {
                        return (
                            // <HorizontalFlatListItem item={item} index={index} parentFlatList={this}>
                            // </HorizontalFlatListItem>
                            <TouchableOpacity 
                            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("../components/Hook")}
                            style={{marginLeft: 20, alignItems: 'center'}}>
                                <Image source={require('../assets/apple.jpeg')} style={{borderRadius:30}}/>
                                <View style={{width: '100%', backgroundColor: '#02ad94', opacity: 0.5}}></View>
                                <Text style={{color: 'white', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize:20, marginEnd: 5, marginTop: 5}}>apple</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        );
                    }}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.hour}
                >

                </FlatList>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
            }
}
```

Comment: Are you using `react-navigation` or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve image from JSON, like

```
const hotFlatListData = [{image: require('../assets/apple.jpeg')},{..}]

<Image source={item.image} style={{borderRadius:30, width:xx, height:xx}}/>
```

Move another page when click, like

```
// remove this and extract "navigation" from function "props"
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ScreenRoute")}>
  ....
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The imagecode work very well. !

How do I move on to another screen script ? An error occurs when the second code is executed. The name of the script is 'Hook'.

Comment: @이원석 I have updated my answer as you can destruct `navigation` from function

Comment: Thank you again for your answer.
But it doesn't work on my code.
After import Hook from '../components/Hook';

I ran both of the codes below.
onPress={() => navigation.navigate("../components/Hook")
onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Hook')

The error 'Can't find variable : navigation' appears...

Comment: @이원석 please share your complete function/code

Comment: @이원석 In your class component, this should work `this.props.navigation.navigate("Hook")` where `Hook` is not the path of the route, It's route actually define in your stack navigator as `name` key

Comment: I wanted to divide up the script, but it ended up being combined. It works well in one place combined. My script structure was called from App.js with HotFlaList in the component file.
app.js > HotFlatList.js > Hook.js
I wanted this kind of structure.
app.js > Hook.js
It's like this right now. :(